# Top and bottom numbers of sqrt

Tags: c++, sqrt

So I am stuck or I confused my self with the following: 
I need to use a for loop to figure out the top and bottom numbers for the square root of a positive integer

ie:

```
Enter Num: 10
Top is 4
Bottom is 3

Enter Num: 16
Top is 4
Bottom is 3

Enter Num: 8
Top is 3
Bottom 2
```

**EDIT:**

I have

```
for(int top =1;top >=num; top++)
```

does `top >=num` go there? I know `10^(1/2)` is `3.16`

Also how are the top and bottom found? I don't know how sqrt(10) top and bottom is 4 and 3... is this with fractions or with simplified squares? I am confused on this problem.

based on the help here is the answer

```
for(int top = 1; top <=num  ; top++) 
{
   if( top * top >= num)
   {
        cout << "Top is " << top ;
        cout << "\nBottom is " << (top-1) << endl;
        top =num +1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to show your code, don't just describe part of it.

Comment: 3 is the largest integer less than `sqrt(10)` and 4 is the smallest integer greater than `sqrt(10)`; hence bottom and top.

Comment: If you're confused, you really should be asking your teacher or professor for help, if only to clarify what they want from you. You should also decide what language you want the solution in, as solutions in Java or C++ can be different.

Comment: First question: `java` or `c++`?  One of these tags needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just loop over integers until you pass the square root:

```
int bottom = 0;
int top = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
    if (i * i > num) {
        top = i;
        break;
    }
    bottom = i;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest replacing `i * i > num` with `i * i >= num`, as it otherwise doesn't behave as specified by OP for numbers which are exact squares (`Enter Num: 16 Top is 4 Bottom is 3`).